# How to hide the extra controls in react-native-video

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I'm using react-native-video and I am trying to figure out how to hide only the two buttons (caption and bar graph thing) in the image below.
I still want the scrubbar and time. Passing controls=false hides everything which I dont want.

This is my current player component setup

```
<Video
          onPlaybackRateChange={onPlaybackRateChange}
          source={{ uri }}
          resizeMode="contain"
          useNativeDriver={true}
          style={styles.video}
          disableTimer={true}
          controls={true}
        />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should hide controls with `controls={true}` prop and use other packages for movie control like [react-native-video-controls](https://github.com/itsnubix/react-native-video-controls) or [react-native-video-player](https://github.com/cornedor/react-native-video-player) as mentioned in [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video#controls)